# Mocking complex 3rd party libraries

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, mstest

I have a class that uses 3rd party FTP library http://ftps.codeplex.com/ and I would like to mock it so that I can unit test just that class and not the FTP library. I have done it but it feels messy to me. In detail, the class uses these methods of AlexPilotti.FTPS.Client.FTPSClient class:

```
public string Connect(string hostname, ESSLSupportMode sslSupportMode)
public ulong PutFile(
    string localFileName, string remoteFileName,
    FileTransferCallback transferCallback)
```

Delegate AlexPilotti.FTPS.Client.FileTransferCallback looks like this:

```
public delegate void FileTransferCallback(
    FTPSClient sender, ETransferActions action, 
    string localObjectName, string remoteObjectName,
    ulong fileTransmittedBytes, ulong? fileTransferSize, ref bool cancel);
```

You can see a problem because PutFile takes the delegate from FTP library and that delegate takes two different types from the library as well. I decided to use generics to decouple from these types.

To be able to create a mock object, I created an interface and then a derived class which is a wrapper of the FTP library functionality.

```
// Interface so that dependency injection can be used.
public delegate void FileTransferCallback<T1, T2>(T1 sender, T2 action,
    string localObjectName, string remoteObjectName,
    ulong fileTransmittedBytes, ulong? fileTransferSize,
    ref bool cancel);

public interface IFTPClient<T1, T2> : IDisposable
{
    string Connect(string hostname, System.Net.NetworkCredential credential);
    ulong PutFile(
        string localFileName, string remoteFileName,
        FileTransferCallback<T1, T2> transferCallback);
}

// Derived class, the wrapper
using FTPSClient = FTPS.Client.FTPSClient;
using ETransferActions = FTPS.Client.ETransferActions;

public class FTPClient : IFTPClient<FTPSClient, ETransferActions>
{
    public FTPClient()
    {
        client = new AlexPilotti.FTPS.Client.FTPSClient();
    }

    public ulong PutFile(
        string localFileName, string remoteFileName,
        FileTransferCallback<FTPSClient, ETransferActions> transferCallback)
    {
        callback = transferCallback;
        return client.PutFile(localFileName, remoteFileName, TransferCallback);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        client.Dispose();
    }

    public string Connect(
        string hostname, System.Net.NetworkCredential credential)
    {
        return client.Connect(hostname, credential, 
            FTPS.Client.ESSLSupportMode.ClearText);
    }

    void TransferCallback(
        FTPS.Client.FTPSClient sender, FTPS.Client.ETransferActions action, 
        string localObjectName, string remoteObjectName,
        ulong fileTransmittedBytes, ulong? fileTransferSize, 
        ref bool cancel)
    {
        callback.Invoke(sender, action, localObjectName, remoteObjectName,
            fileTransmittedBytes, fileTransferSize, ref cancel);
    }

    private AlexPilotti.FTPS.Client.FTPSClient client;
    private FileTransferCallback<FTPSClient, ETransferActions> callback;
}
```

Here goes a class that uses this interface and which I unit test. I stripped it down a bit so only the Connect method is used but I hope it still illustrates my problem.

```
public class FTPServerConnection<T1, T2>
{
    public void Init(
        IFTPClient<T1, T2> client, string serverName,
        string userName, string passwd)
    {
        IsConnected = false;

        ServerName = serverName;
        UserName = userName;
        Passwd = passwd;

        ftpClient = client;

        Connect();
    }

    public void Connect()
    {
        ftpClient.Connect(
           ServerName,
           new System.Net.NetworkCredential(UserName, Passwd));
    }

    public string ServerName { protected set; get; }
    public string UserName { protected set; get; }
    public string Passwd { protected set; get; }

    public bool IsConnected { protected set; get; }

    private IFTPClient<T1, T2> ftpClient;
}
```

And finally the unit test:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void FTPServerConnectionConstructorTest()
{
    var ftpClient = new Mock<IFTPClient<object, object>>();
    var ftpServer = new FTPServerConnection<object, object>();
    ftpServer.Init(ftpClient.Object, "1.2.3.4", "user", "passwd");

    Assert.AreEqual("1.2.3.4", ftpServer.ServerName);
    Assert.AreEqual("user", ftpServer.UserName);
    Assert.AreEqual("passwd", ftpServer.Passwd);
}
```

What is the usual approach in situations like this one? My approach seems to be messy and I am wondering if there is easier way of doing it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this only feels messy because you've had that third party delegate to cope with, but it looks like a pretty standard abstraction / mocking approach to me.

My only comment would be that the structure of `FTPServerConnection` looks a bit non-standard; the way it's written you have to instantiate one in an invalid state (*i.e.* one with no client details) then call `Init()`, which itself calls `Connect()` (which from the look of your test is never called by a client of the server class). It would be more normal I'd say to have the arguments to `Init()` supplied in the `FTPServerConnection` constructor, then remove the `Init()` method altogether and have the client do this:

```
var ftpClient = new Mock<IFTPClient<object, object>>();

using (var ftpServer = new FTPServerConnection<object, object>(
     ftpClient.Object,
     "1.2.3.4",
     "user",
     "passwd"))
{
    ftpServer.Connect();
}
```

...but again, regarding the way you've abstracted the FTP library, I think that's a decent way of doing it :)

Comment: I was afraid there is no other way of doing it ;) Thanks for that Init() method, I will change it.